# regular expression for many ips separated by comma

Tags: regex

i'm intended to build a regular expression that will match with a block of ips separated by comma.
well as far as i have is a regullar expression for ips and a comma followed by a breakline character, but i need to set this condition:

if threre is the last line (no breakline char) comma is optional
if there is evrything else, must be a comma followed by breakline.

would you help me to complete the regex please ?

this is the regex that i'm building

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(,\n)?)*
```

this is the testing block

```
192.168.1.1,
192.56.3.23,
189.35.2.2,
198.23.45.56
192.168.3.24
```

the 198.23.45.56 shouldn't be valid since is not the last line and there is not a comma at the end of the line.

I'm using this validator online http://regexpal.com/ to test the regex.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(,\n|,?$))
```

And use the 'g' flag to include multiple matches ('dot matches all' checkbox in http://regexpal.com).

Comment: actually your modification helped me, i did some modification since what i want is to validate the whole block instead of any line and do the global match. thank you BTW this is the regex that i used ^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(,\n|,?))*$

Comment: can u give regex for only two ip , separated by comma eg. 192.168.1.1,
192.56.3.23

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like a regular expression if you're using such a strict scheme. Try myIpList = myIpString.split(',\n')

Comment: That won't enforce IPv4 addresses.  It also won't split out the last 2 addresses in the list.

Comment: @Roy this is because i'm using this jquery plugin and i'm trying to extend this regex within this method https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/additional-methods.js#L304

Comment: @PinnyM: alexserver said that the last wasn't valid because it didn't have the comma anyway. alexserver: Good to hear you got a solution. ;)