# Regex for comma seperated IPs list which could have single or masked IPs

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

I am looking for valid .NET Regex in order to validate a string containing comma separated list of IPs. IPs could be single IPs (**192.168.12.5**), Masked IPs (**192.168.0.0;255.255.0.0**) or CIDR notation (**192.168.0.0/16**).

one sample correct input by user could be:

**192.168.12.5,192.168.15.7,192.168.0.0;255.255.0.0,192.168.0.0/16**

one sample in-correct input:

192.168.12.5,**192.168.15**,**192.168.0.0;255.255.0.0;255.255.0.0**,192.168.0.0/16

This string can be empty as well. I'll use the regex to validate the input at client/server side using DataAnnotation regex matching in MVC3.

Comment: I'm sure you know the drill by now: please show us what have you tried so far, even if it does not work.

Comment: i tried a lot to be honest. I went into the way as given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879964/regular-expression-for-many-ips-separated-by-comma

Comment: What should be selected for `192.168.0.0/16`? You included `;` in your input string, is this a typo? Or is it comma/semi-colon delimited? How is your question different from the one you linked?

Comment: I want to validate the string using data annotation regex matching in MVC3. ";" is used to separate IP from mask.

Comment: Is `192.168.0.0/16` valid?

Comment: I did edit. Yes it is valid.

Comment: @RyanGates: Ans of your question: How is your question different from the one you linked?: linked question is for comma separated single IPs only. My question is for comma separated single, masked, cidr IP notations.

Comment: Are the asterisks part of the format for the incorrect input? Or are they incorrect formatting?

Comment: it is incorrect formatting..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be precise, it's not enough to simply validate that each octet contains three digits; you need to validate that it's between 0 and 255. This leads to the following expression for a single IP address:

```
\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\b
```

To validate a mask, you'll need to repeat the expression. To validate a CIDR notation suffix, you need a number between 0 and 32:

```
\/(3[0-2]|[012]?\d)
```

You'll then need to repeat the entire group for the comma-separated list. Putting it all together, with white-space and comments added for clarity:

```
# Start of line:
^
(
  (
    # An IP address:
    \b((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\b

    # Optionally followed by either:
    (
      # a CIDR suffix:
      (\/(3[0-2]|[012]?\d))
    |
      # or a subnet mask:
      ;\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\b
    )?
  )

  # Followed by a comma and optional white-space
  ,\s*
)
# Zero or more times:
*

# Followed by:
(
  # An IP address:
  \b((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\b

  # Optionally followed by either:
  (
    # a CIDR suffix
    (\/(3[0-2]|[012]?\d))
  |
    # or a subnet mask:
    ;\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d{1,2})\b
  )?
)
# Zero or once (to allow empty strings):
?

# End of line
$
```

Of course, this will only support IPv4 addresses.

Comment: This has got fair chances to be the accepted answer. I am not able to test it at the moment. Hope this would be compatible for IE as well, I have seen my other regx failing to validate in IE in recent past.

Comment: @Amyz: If you take out the white-space and comments, this should work for client-side validation as well.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will validate against the requirements you described.

```
([\d]{1,3}.[\d]{1,3}.[\d]{1,3}.[\d]{1,3}[/]*[\d]{0,3}[,;]*)*
```

Comment: sorry for not being clear to you. I dont want to grab each. I want to validate the string using data annotation regex matching in MVC3.

Comment: I am not able to test it at the moment. but it looks like you have used comma as well as semicolon as delimiter. I need to use only comma as delimiter between different IPs. semicolon could be used to seperate IP from its mask for only masked IPs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
^(?!^;|.*,$)(;?\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3}){3}(/\d{1,3})?,?)*$
```

Comment: I dont think this would validate masked ips

Comment: I am not able to test it at the moment. VS stuck somewhere. but you haven't used semicolon (;) anywhere?