# use regex to match multiple ip address separated by comma or only one ip address?

Tags: regex

it can check like:

"192.168.1.2,118.123.10.25,123.145.67.88"

and it can also check "192.168.4.56" ??

Comment: I have an answer. But giving you the answer will encourage people to post question with very low quality. take the [tour] and read how to ask with a [mcve]

Comment: check this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UJfs8x/1) for finding answer, and kindly care about the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes when i asked this question I have found the similar questions on the net, but the best answers does not worked for me. I use laravel5's validation in FormRequest file.

A similar question's answer is :

```
/^((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)(,|,?$))$/
```

(this one ↑　doesnot worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879964/regular-expression-for-many-ips-separated-by-comma))

this one worked for me :

```
/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}(,|,?$)$/
```